# SQL order of commands

Tags: sql

I have an issue where I'm looking in BRKRMASTID where I only want NULL values. And when I have a null value I want BRKR_FEE_PCT OR BRKR_FEE_AMT to not be 0. I have typed my code and for some reason I am still getting BRKRMASTID with values.

How can I make SQL only return values that are NULL and still have either BRKR_FEE_PCT or BRKR_FEE_AMT that are not equal to 0.

```
select * 

from dbo.BRKRREF

where BRKRMASTID is null
or BRKR_FEE_PCT <> 0
or BRKR_FEE_AMT <> 0
```

Thanks for those who helped me so quickly. This edit is for a part 2 of the same issue. How can I get values *where BRKMASTID is Null or = '0'* with the same criteria for BRKR_FEE_PCT and BRKR_FEE_AMT?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: you need to update your first `or` to `and` and then group the other 2 conditions with an `or`

Comment: Actually somebody posted a response but it was deleted. They told me to use an AND function with parenthesis. So the original question has been answered.

Comment: It was me the one that deleted, sorry I thought I misunderstood the question, answer is back

Comment: This edit is for a part 2 of the same issue. How can I get values where BRKMASTID is Null or = '0' with the same criteria for BRKR_FEE_PCT and BRKR_FEE_AMT?  `WHERE (BRKRMASTID is null or BRKRMASTID =0)
AND (BRKR_FEE_PCT <> 0
or BRKR_FEE_AMT <> 0)`  is brkmastid numeric or character data?  you don't need apostrophe around the '0' if numeric you do if text so implicit casting doesn't occur.

Comment: Do not change your question if you have another question, you need to ask another question by opening a brand new question. Otherwise the answers will no longer make sense.

Comment: @xQbert My guess is that BRKRMASTID is numeric but I still get different results if I have it set as NULL or '0' so that's why I need both

Comment: @CodingYoshi my 2nd question is entirely related to my first part. It's simply an addition now that I have the first part done.

Comment: @go.surf13 you'll note that I added () around the first limit an or and check for both is null or =0.  which I believe addresses the question.  BRKRMASTID must be either null or 0 and either BRKR_FEE_PCT or BRKR_FEE_AMT must not be 0.

Comment: @xQbert Ok, now I ran into something odd. When I take out the parenthesis I have 1745 rows but when the parenthesis are on I have 32 rows. Can you please explain why it's vastly different to have parenthesis or not?

Comment: If you're familiar with Algebra; then you already know the answer (8+2) -(3+2) = 5 vs 8+2-3+2 = 9.  ()'s matter. () tell the engine in what order to evaluate the expression.  So without the ()'s the engine is treating the value just like algebra left to right. so (BRKRMASTID is null or (BRKRMASTID =0 AND BRKR_FEE_PCT <> 0)) or BRKR_FEE_AMT <> 0 so you'd get back any one with brkr_fee_Amount <> 0 or any one with brkrmastid null or anyone that's 0 and the brkr_fee_pct is not zero.  The question is; is our understanding of your requirement correct so do we ahve the ()'s in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like your question states, "How can I make SQL only return values that are NULL **AND** still have either BRKR_FEE_PCT or BRKR_FEE_AMT that are not equal to 0."

```
select * 

from dbo.BRKRREF

where BRKRMASTID is null
AND (BRKR_FEE_PCT <> 0
     or BRKR_FEE_AMT <> 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 

from dbo.BRKRREF

where BRKRMASTID is null
and (BRKR_FEE_PCT <> 0 or
BRKR_FEE_AMT <> 0)
```